# async.each callback after finishing all iterations

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have been banging my head against this piece of code for a few hours now. Moreover I have used  "**async.each**" multiple times before. May be the code just needs a different set of eyes to work. Here's the code and the problem.

```
async.each(process.argv, function(file, callback){
    runFile(file, callback);

}, function(err){
    console.log("Here is the error!:" + err +"files to unstage: " + filesToUnstage)

    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else{
        if(filesToUnstage) {
            __unstage();
        }
    }
});
```

runFile:

```
function runFile(filename, callback) {
    // Do a bunch of stuff ....
    __parseOutput(output, callback);
}
```

__parseOutput:

```
function __parseOutput(output, callback){
    //Do some if else statement and do console.log
    return callback(null);
}
```

**Problem:** The final callback i.e. `function(err){..}` of `async.each` is not called after all the iterations have finished.

Comment: is your runFile executed?  Also is process.argv an empty array?

Comment: Yup! everything is executed just fine and I get the desired outputs from all the functions except the final callback as mentioned above. No `process.argv` is not empty (cross-checked).

Comment: Into your `//Do some if else statement and do console.log` maybe yo don't call your callback

Comment: You should try `console.log(callback)` inside every function in order to see if you are actually passing it

Comment: @Gepser As you can see there is a `return callback(null)` just after `//Do some if else statement and do console.log`. This `callback` is outside all the `if else` statements and at the end of the `__parseOutput` function. Thanks for the suggestion on `console.log(callback)` but I have tried that already and it contains the right `callback` (throw err if called more than once etc...)

Comment: Ok @Gautam, and probably not your problem but why are you using `return callback`? and not calling the `callback` directly?

Comment: Hey @Gepser good point. If I have a few lines of code after a `callback` then `javascript` will execute those lines `asynchronously` which was sometimes not desirable in my specific case. So as a good coding practice and to prevent this asynchronous behavior I started putting `return` before `callback` to exit the function immediately. Again it is case to case basis. In this particular case I have tried without `return` also but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Gautam, I copied your code and works fine, the problem is not here. Maybe you are missing a callback or something but I can't say it without looking more code.

Comment: Thanks @Gepser! I did exactly what you suggested and found that there was one function (not shown here) that was running asynchronously causing all the problems. I am able to successfully get the callback now.

Comment: I am happy to read that.

Answer (score 1):

All the problem was being caused by an asynchronous method being called in between callbacks. I waited for this problematic function to complete and then called the `callback`. In my case I used `async.waterfall` to wait as I had to pass values from one to the other. For similar problems, please read the comments of this question and specifically those by `@Gepser`.